# if(isset()) always displays true?

Tags: php

I have 4 required fields.. I'm using AJAX form processing and when the form is submitted before it does anything it checks if the forum elements were empty or not. With the following **PHP** code.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['faq_topic'], $_REQUEST['faq_detail'], $_REQUEST['faq_name'], $_REQUEST['faq_email'])){
```

Now even if the forms are left empty they get submitted for some reason? Why would this happen? Doesn't that make it impossible for that to happen? The form works flawlessly other than the fact that it can submit blank data..

Here is the entire script... Minus the HTML/jQuery

```
// Required Configuration
include_once('required.php');

// get data that sent from form
$topic=$_REQUEST['faq_topic'];
$detail=$_REQUEST['faq_detail'];
$name=$_REQUEST['faq_name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['faq_email'];

// check if all forms are filled out
if(isset($_REQUEST['faq_topic'], $_REQUEST['faq_detail'], $_REQUEST['faq_name'], $_REQUEST['faq_email'])){
    // Format Date And Time
    $datetime=date("m/d/y h:i");
    // SQL Insert Statement
    $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name_question(topic, detail, name, email, datetime)VALUES('$topic', '$detail', '$name', '$email', '$datetime')";
    // Check If SQL Went Through
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    // Now Print Out Success Or MySQL Error
    if($result){
        $html = '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>You <strong>successfully</strong> submited a question to the FAQ bored.</div>';
        print($html);
    }
        else {
        $html = '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>Opps there was a problem on our end... Please try again later.</div>';
        print($html);
    }
    // Close MySQL Connection
    mysql_close();
} else {
    // If the required items were not filled out print the following
    $html = '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>All</strong> forms are required.</div>';
    print($html);
}
```

If you have suggestions it would be amazing!!! Also if you have any other comments about something I am doing wrong in my code it would be neat too if you could help me there.

**Many thanks in advance!!**

Best Regards!

Comment: You should be using `filter_var` to validate/sanitize your form input on the server side (never trust user input). Also the `mysql_` family of functions have long been deprecated, use mysqli or PDO with prepared queries instead.

Comment: @OscarM. how can i implement filter_var and mysqli with prepared?

Comment: Use [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) to sanitize your `$_REQUEST` inputs. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to connect and send your query to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset` checks if the variable is set and it will be set even if the variable contains the empty string.

If you want to check if the variable is empty or not you should use `empty` instead.

Do something like

```
$topic=trim($_REQUEST['faq_topic']);
$detail=trim($_REQUEST['faq_detail']);
$name=trim($_REQUEST['faq_name']);
$email=trim($_REQUEST['faq_email']);

if (!empty($topic) && !empty($detail) && !empty($name) && !empty($email)) {
```

Comment: So same syntax but replace isset with empty?

Comment: Combine it with `trim()` and you have a winner

Comment: Asprin whats trim do?

Comment: @kmgilbert100: trim removes whitespace (so spaces, tab and new lines characters).

Comment: @WizKid So if(trim(empty($_REQUEST['faq_topic'], $_REQUEST['faq_detail'], $_REQUEST['faq_name'], $_REQUEST['faq_email']))){ wuold do the trick?

Comment: No, trim and empty takes one variable. I updated with a code example

Comment: @kmgilbert100 - In the future, if you have questions about what a particular function does, I recommend reading the official [PHP documentation](http://us3.php.net/docs.php) on that function.  It will tell you the parameters it takes, what it outputs and what the function is useful for.

Answer (score 0):

What isset() checks is if the variable is defined at all.  Since I'm assuming you are posting the variables empty, the variables are set, but with empty values.

What you need to use instead is [empty()](https://www.php.net/empty) which will determine whether or not the value of the variable is left blank.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['faq_topic']) && !empty($_REQUEST['faq_detail']) && empty($_REQUEST['faq_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['faq_email']))
```

Comment: Wrong! `isset()` can be used with multiple parameters separated with a comma

Comment: and `isset($a, $b, $c)` means that all needs to be set. So it would be the same as `isset($a) && isset($b) && isset($c)`

And empty returns true if the variable is empty. And he wanted to know if all of them was not empty. So it should be `!empty($a) && !empty($b) && !empty($c)`

Comment: @asprin - Weird, I went to the official PHP documentation to first confirm.  I missed the small blurb mentioning it accepted multiple parameters, my bad.

Comment: @WizKid - You're right.   I should probably not answer questions when running on no sleep lol

Comment: No worries. I tend to miss out on small bits of information many times too

Answer (score 0):

To remove warnings you could do

```
$topic= isset($_REQUEST['faq_topic']) ? $_REQUEST['faq_topic'] : '';
$detail= isset( $_REQUEST['faq_detail'] ) ? $_REQUEST['faq_detail'] : '';
```

And then ...

```
if( !empty($topic) && !empty($detail) ... ) 
{
  ...
}
```

This might look like an overkill but you will get rid of some warnings and check for empty strings.

You could use trim(...) if you don't want to allow blank spaces.

Comment: In this case it would hide errors. Because he have a form with all 4 fields. So the only case one of them are not set it means that something is wrong with the form. So he probably want an error if that happens